# manifest.json, content_scripts limit matching to url with port number

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Google chrome extension that should only run when the URL matches `http://*:8000/*`

Part of my manifest.json file:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*:8000/*"],
    "js" : ["client.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
}]
```

I get the following error when trying to pack the extension.

```
Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]': Invalid host wildcard.
```

If I change `matches` to `<all_url>` it packs properly and works but on every page.

How can I get it to work only with a URL that contains port 8000?

Comment: `"matches":["<all_urls>"], "include_globs": ["http://*:8000/*"]` might work, but I think it might also match `http://foo.com/bar/:8000/baz`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to programmatically check the port number and stop the evaluation of the script if it's not the port you want. You can check `window.location.port` (fyi, which is an empty string for port 80 when on `http`) or `window.location.host` which includes the hostname and port (but not `window.location.hostname`- it doesn't include the port). So, I'd start my script with something like this:

```
(window.location.port === "8000") && (function() {
    // your code...
})();
```