# Would a colon in matches URL break my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

There is a site that I'm using that has a horrible interface. I wanted to "fix it up a bit" and insert some custom CSS. I have my chrome extension working using google.com but can't get it to work on the target site. The only thing I can work out is maybe it's because of the colon in the matches URL?

http://subdomain.subdomain.subdomain.edu.au:82/Folder/

Strangely the javascript I have done does work (adds a class to ) so I am thinking maybe there is something else that is a problem. Also note that the target site is behind the u/p but is not on a https server - does this matter?
Here is the complete manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Makes the site prettier.",
  "version": "1.5",
  "author": "daniel",
  "icons": { "16": "/icons/icon16.png",
           "48": "/icons/icon48.png",
          "128": "/icons/icon128.png"
          },

  "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://subdomain.subdomain.subdomain.edu.au:82/Folder/*"],
        "css": ["style.css"],
        "js": ["script.js"]
    }]
}
```

and here is the CSS file:

```
html body.customclass {background-color: #FF0;}
```

and here is the JS file:

```
document.body.classList.add("customclass");
```

Comment: the `:` is inside a quoted string, so it's not relevant to the containing syntax (e.g. javascript).

Comment: That's what I thought @MarcB but I am at a loss to work out what is going wrong. The css change is reflected in other sites and the javascript is working everywhere. I don't have a specificity issue as the CSS doesn't even appear in the inspector. It's as if it's not recognised.

Comment: seems like a port issue to me, try doing something like `"http://*:82/*"` as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003543/manifest-json-content-scripts-limit-matching-to-url-with-port-number

Comment: I tried doing all_urls and it works so it must be something to do with the port issue. I looked at @1337holiday's suggested solution but that fixes it for JS (as I said before, JS is working) so I am not sure how that answer fixes the matches URL problem or missing CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, after much google searching I found the relevant information:
https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/46/admin/URL_patterns#match_ports

So the trick was to wildcard the port rather than state it.

```
"matches": ["http://subdomain.subdomain.subdomain.edu.au:*/Folder/*"]
```

This fixes my issue (it doesn't really matter for me which port gets used) but there should be a better way to match urls with a port number so that specific ports (i.e. :82) works.

Comment: The documentation you're referring to is not relevant to Chrome extensions. The correct documentation is found at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html, but it doesn't mention ports at all.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that it was from somewhere else but I figured becasue it was from google and talked about similar things that it must be documentation that was forgotten from the source you refer to..... then it worked! :) Thanks though for clarifying that.

Comment: FYI the bug report about the documentation's quality can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=318195